# WebRtc: Failed to set SSL role for the transport

Tags: ssl, webrtc

When connecting from a device to a device, this error occurs: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): OperationError: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to apply the description for 0: Failed to set SSL role for the transport..
Error: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to apply the description for 0: Failed to set SSL role for the transport..

Comment: Error In Google Chrome / Microsoft Edge!